# MongoDB, Marshalling, JAXB and JSON

Tags: java, mongodb, jaxb, jersey, marshalling

So I am really confused, so hopefully what I am asking makes sense. I should note that this is for homework but I am just asking for help on a small part.

Here are simplified and genericized versions of my data classes:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="item")
@XmlType(propOrder={"name", "value"})
public class Item {

    private String name;
    private int value;

    @XmlElement(name="name")    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="value")   
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

and

```
@XmlRootElement(name="itemcontainer")
@XmlType(propOrder={ "name", "items"})
public class ItemContainer {

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Item> items;

    @XmlElement(name="name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="items")
    public ArrayList<Item> getItem() {
        return item;
    }
}
```

What I need to be able to do is convert ItemContainer objects back and forth between JSON to store in a MongoDB database. (Has to be MongoDB)

From what I understand ArrayLists cannot be marshalled.

What I am going to eventually need to do is read from a MongoDB database, unmarshall the JSON into Java objects, perform operations on these objects and then marshall them back into JSON to store in the database.

What do I need to change or do to allow me to make conversions between JSON and ItemContainer?

Comment: How will you insert the JSON into the db? I can't see any function that would accept a String (that represents a JSON) to be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

Below is how you could support your use case with MOXy's JSON-binding.

**Foo**

Below is the Java model we will use for this example.

```
public class Foo {

    private String bar;

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` that contains the following content in the same package as your domain model (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html)

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Foo.class}, properties);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StreamSource json = new StreamSource("src/forum15728638/input.json");
        List<Foo> foos = (List<Foo>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(json, Foo.class).getValue();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foos, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.json/Output**

```
[ {
   "bar" : "Hello"
}, {
   "bar" : "World"
} ]
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html

Comment: In my application, I have to specify the namespace information in `package-info.java` only then `@XmlPath` fields were mapped to DTO. Is it required to specify? What is the use of this?